# Converting a .NET type (System.Converter) to a Python type with Python.NET

Tags: python, c#, python.net, infer.net

I am trying to write the Python.NET equivalent of [this C# code](https://github.com/dotnet/infer/blob/dcc3503b7d808bd3d6bf0dd8ec1e2f2ef4356afb/src/Examples/MotifFinder/Program.cs#L155):

```
Util.ArrayInit(motifPositionData[i], j => backgroundDist.Sample());
```

However, [the `Util.ArrayInit()` method](https://github.com/dotnet/infer/blob/dcc3503b7d808bd3d6bf0dd8ec1e2f2ef4356afb/src/Runtime/Core/Utils/Util.cs#L265) accepts an `int` and a [Converter<TInput,TOutput> Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.converter-2?view=net-5.0) --- of which I have no idea what the Python equivalent would be. I tried a lambda but it didn't work:

```
Util.ArrayInit(1, lambda x: 1)
TypeError: No method matches given arguments for ArrayInit: (<class 'int'>, <class 'function'>)
```

Question 1: How can I inspect which arguments do have a matching method, from the Python debugger/console? (Maybe not possible.)

Question 2:
Would I need to create a [custom object marshalling](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Codecs:-customizing-object-marshalling-between-.NET-and-Python) from a Python `function` (e.g. a lambda) to a .NET `System.Converter`, the way that Python `int` is automatically converted to a .NET `System.Int32`... Or is there as simpler way of doing this?

---

I have circumvented this by not using `Util.ArrayInit` in the first place, but am still curious about the case doing so is not as trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import clr
>>> from System import Converter
>>> c = Converter[int, str](lambda i: str(i))
>>> c(42)
'42'
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27662105)

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar this code snippet is an answer to the posed question.

Comment: @LOST wow, I tried this but didn't specify the types `[int, str]`! Maybe even more useful for me than your answer is *how* you got to this answer, if I may ask you to walk me through your process of figuring this out?

Comment: @ChristabellaIrwanto , well, I am one of maintainers of Python.NET. Basically the idea is that from Python lambda it is, generally speaking, impossible to figure out the return type. So you have to [specify type parameters explicitly](https://pythonnet.github.io/#using-generics)